# How many distinct ring homomorphisms are there from Z to Z? From Z x Z to Z?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> How many distinct ring homomorphisms are there from Z to Z? From Z x Z to Z?

I'm a little lost as to what this question is asking. So far I'm guessing all ring homomorphisms from Z to Z would be of form $$x\rightarrow ax$$ But I'm kind of lost conceptually on how to think about this.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general $\varphi:x\mapsto ax$ won't satisfy $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$.

Comment: Are you considering unitary ring homomorphisms?

Comment: @Charter Yes in our textbook we only consider unitary.

Comment: If its unitary it should be stated

Comment: One first step might be $$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}  \cong \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x(1-x)) $$ Another first step might be $$\hom_{\mathrm{AbGrp}}(X \times Y, Z) \cong \hom_{\mathrm{AbGrp}}(X, Z) \times \hom_{\mathrm{AbGrp}}(Y, Z)$$

Answer (score 2):

For homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, note that $f$ is determined by $f(1)$, since $f(n)=n\cdot f(1)$. Since the homomorphism is required to be unital, $f(1)=1$, so $f=\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{Z}$.

---

For homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, note again that such a homomorphism is completely determined by $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$. Furthermore, since $(1,1)$ is the multiplicative identity of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, we have $$f(1,0)+f(0,1)=f((1,0)+(0,1))=f(1,1)=1$$ Since the homomorphism must preserve multiplication, $$0=f(0,0)=f((1,0)\cdot(0,1))=f(1,0)\cdot f(0,1)$$ Thus, one of $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ should be zero, and another should by $1$.

We conclude that there are only two homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$: the projections on the first and second coordinate.

Answer (score -2):

For see all rings homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Z$ you can remember that $f$ is also a abelian group homomorphism and $\Bbb Z$ is a cyclic group. Then there exists only two homomorphism, the identity and $f(x)=-x$ and they are also ring homomorphism.

On other hand, if $f:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Z$ is a ring homomorphism such that $f(a,b)=1$. And considered $f(1,0)=m$, $f(0,1)=n$. I assume that you definition of ring homomorphism consider that $f(1)=1$. So how many different values or a and b you have?

Comment: If talking about non-unital homomorphisms, there are *much* more then these two. The question asks for unital ring homomorphisms, and $f(x)=-x$ is not unital.